# Getting an error from a dot-net created function of getDataAsync in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I have:

```
[OperationContract]
string GetData(string input);
```

I get an error saying `cannot have two operations in the same contract with the same name, methods GetDataAsync and GetData in type....violate this rule`

But I didn't configure any `GetDataAsync` function! So why is the async function being automatically created? How do I stop it (because I don't need that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when you have methods [OperationContract] with same name, no matter if those methods receives different parameters, you can't name methods with same name.

and the Ansy method is created automatically when you add the service reference, but you can uncheck this option in the service reference.

Comment: I understand the error, it's more the added async function. How do I uncheck automatically adding the async methods?

Comment: answering my own comment questoin: in `add service reference` hit `advanced` then uncheck `allow generation of asynchronous operations`